# run a program from network location as scheduled task

Tags: windows-server-2008, task-scheduler

I am running a windows server 2008 R2.

When trying to run a scheduled task (manually and automatically triggered), the Last Run Time results in `"Access is Denied"`. History shows: `Task Scheduler failed to launch action "\\uncpath\uncpath\file.exe"`

As you can see the file is located on a networklocation. It requires administratorprivileges to run successfully, which it has. When I navigate to the networklocation and run the executable, it executes as expected. However, the task shows the access is denied-error.

How can I get my task to run correctly (and the program)?

- Note: when creating this task on my local (Windows 8.1) machine, the task executes normally.
- Note 2: When creating a local .cmd file and having that get executed as the task; with in the .cmd file the execution of the "network-executable", the .cmd runs but the executable does not.
- Note 3: Shortening the path to exclude spaces from the uacpath did not result in the executable working as expected.
- Note 4: Placing the executable locally (on the server 2008), the executable gets fired as normally.

Addition, the task:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2014-05-21T11:35:54.0775312</Date>
    <Author>xxxx</Author>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <TimeTrigger>
      <Repetition>
        <Interval>PT1H</Interval>
        <StopAtDurationEnd>false</StopAtDurationEnd>
      </Repetition>
      <StartBoundary>2014-05-21T11:34:33.0479662</StartBoundary>
      <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT30M</ExecutionTimeLimit>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    </TimeTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>xxxx</UserId>
      <LogonType>Password</LogonType>
      <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>P3D</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>"\\uncpath\file.exe"</Command>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

Comment: Could you please export the scheduled task to XML so that we can see the exact configuration of the scheduled task?

Comment: I have added the tasks' xml. Some sensitive information is removed from it, but no actual lines.

Comment: Does the user that you specified have access to the network location?

Comment: Yes, the user has access.

Comment: Have you tried setting the "Start in" parameter to be a local drive?

Comment: I have tried that also, it did not work.